# Weird error, comparing a char to a string (p == "cancel")

Tags: c, if-statement, char

I'm trying to do a basic if statement and I'm getting this weird error with my string.

Error 1:

> Comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'char *')

Error 2:

> Result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified (use strncmp instead)

Here is a copy of the function is all occurs in.

```
int logOn(int *par)
{
    char p;
    printf("Log into student records system\nEnter password or type cancel to leave\n>");
    scanf("%s", &p);

        if(p == *PASSWORD1 | p ==  *PASSWORD2 | p ==  *PASSWORD3)
        {
            *par = 2;
        }
        else if (p = "cancel")
        {
            *par = 3;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nIncorrect password try again\n");
        }

    return 0;
}
```

The error is occurring on the `else if` statement line (`p = "cancel"`).

Comment: p = "cancel" assigns "cancel" to p, instead of comparing it.  Change it to p == "cancel"

Comment: `==` as above said. Also, `p` is a `char`, `"cancel"` is a `char*`, they won't be equal. Do you mean `p` to be a `char*`? You should be using `strcmp` then to compare strings.

Comment: That code is destined for undefined behavior. You're reading a string of chars via `%s` into a *single* `char`. Having only space for one element (and it *better* be the nullchar terminator), that means that `scanf` will only be valid if the resulting string read has *no length*.

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of things wrong here.

1. To compare values, use `==` not `=`.
2. The logical *or* operator is `||` not `|`.
3. `char p` makes room for a single character. You can't store a multi-character password in a `char` variable. You'll need a string.
4. You can't compare strings with `==`. `p == *PASSWORD1` won't work. I'll leave it to you to figure out what does work. It's easy enough to search for.

Answer (score 1):

Which function to use for comparison of strings lies in the error thrown by the compiler itself.
(look for the function in error no 2 that you posted and google for it.)